Entity Framework Core - SqlException Invalid object name
In EF Core 7.0, I have created the new table creation as like below and I see table in db also, but I'm seeing invalid object error when my code hit the logic.
I get this error:

SqlException: Invalid object name 'NewTableReqs'

DbContext:
public DbSet<NewTableReq> NewTableReqs { get; set; }

Model.NewTableReq implementation:
namespace Project.Models
{
    public class NewTableReq
    {
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int NewTableReqID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int FlagID { get; set; }
    } 
}


Did you check database? it has table 'NewTableReqs'. Did you run database migration to create DB and tables?

Couple of ideas to debug:
If you see the table, make sure there are not any misspellings.
Also double check your connection string - make sure that Initial Catalog is set to database containing the NewTableReqs.
Also, try running Add-Migration to see what changes are between your context model and database model - maybe there is some difference between EF model and database?

This isn't really an answer, is it? It should really be in the comments.
